# Grouping SQL elements with XSL

Tags: sql, xslt

I've been working on a XSL style sheet for a specific SQL query table.  I would like to group the results by 'tcode' and sum the values of each of the number columns.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="h_ind h_year h_code" />

<xsl:variable name="v_warning"  select="CustomDeferredReport/title/ds_type" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<HTML>
  <BODY>

    <TABLE>
      <TR valign="top">
        <TD style="color:black; font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold" width="800">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$v_warning = '1'">
              <xsl:value-of select="CustomDeferredReport/title/rpt_title" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="CustomDeferredReport/title/rpt_warning" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$v_warning = 1">
        <TABLE>
          <TR style="text-decoration: underline; font-family: arial; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold">
            <BOLD>
              <TD width="100">Code</TD>
              <TD width="200">Name</TD>
              <TD width="100">Beginning Balance</TD>
              <TD width="100">Current Activity</TD>
              <TD width="100">Other Activity</TD>
              <TD width="100">Balance Sheet Only Activity</TD>
              <TD width="100">Ending Balance</TD>
            </BOLD>
          </TR>

          <xsl:for-each select='/CustomDeferredReport/temps'>
            <TR style="font-family: arial; font-size: 8pt">
              <TD><xsl:value-of select='tcode'/></TD>
              <TD><xsl:value-of select='tname'/></TD>
              <TD align="right"><xsl:value-of select='tbbal'/></TD>
              <TD align="right"><xsl:value-of select='tdiff'/></TD>
              <TD align="right"><xsl:value-of select='tothd'/></TD>
              <TD align="right"><xsl:value-of select='tbsd'/></TD>
              <TD align="right"><xsl:value-of select='tebal'/></TD>
            </TR>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </TABLE>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>

  </BODY>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you show a (small) sample of the input XML (or at least the table data), but more importantly how you expect the output to look when it is grouped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

In XSLT there is a very common grouping technique you can use that involves a key and the generate-id() function, it is called muenchian grouping (Google it).

Anyhow, I added a key at the top of your solution called, key_t-code, and then use it several times in the solution.  The trick here is when itterating over the for-each loop to only do something, in your case sum the nodes when you encounter the loop the first time, achieved by using the key and the generate-id.  Enough said.  An example is worth a thousand words.  Here you go... oh, I did have to correct your XSLT n a couple of places.  Mostly your context was off here and there.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="h_ind h_year h_code" />

    <xsl:key name="key_t-code" match="temps" use="tcode"/>

    <xsl:variable name="v_warning"  select="/CustomDeferredReport/title/ds_type" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <HTML>
            <BODY>

                <TABLE>
                    <TR valign="top">
                        <TD style="color:black; font-family: arial; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold" width="800">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$v_warning = '1'">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="CustomDeferredReport/title/rpt_title" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="CustomDeferredReport/title/rpt_warning" />
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$v_warning = 1">
                        <TABLE>
                            <TR style="text-decoration: underline; font-family: arial; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold">
                                <BOLD>
                                    <TD width="100">Code</TD>
                                    <TD width="200">Name</TD>
                                    <TD width="100">Beginning Balance</TD>
                                    <TD width="100">Current Activity</TD>
                                    <TD width="100">Other Activity</TD>
                                    <TD width="100">Balance Sheet Only Activity</TD>
                                    <TD width="100">Ending Balance</TD>
                                </BOLD>
                            </TR>

                            <xsl:for-each select='CustomDeferredReport/temps'>
                                <xsl:if test="generate-id(key('key_t-code', tcode)[1]) = generate-id(.)">
                                <TR style="font-family: arial; font-size: 8pt">
                                    <TD><xsl:value-of select='tcode'/></TD>
                                    <TD><xsl:value-of select='tname'/></TD>
                                    <TD align="right"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('key_t-code', tcode)/tbbal)"/></TD>
                                    <TD align="right"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('key_t-code', tcode)/tdiff)"/></TD>
                                    <TD align="right"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('key_t-code', tcode)/tothd)"/></TD>
                                    <TD align="right"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('key_t-code', tcode)/tbsd)"/></TD>
                                    <TD align="right"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('key_t-code', tcode)/tebal)"/></TD>
                                </TR>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </TABLE>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

            </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomDeferredReport>
    <title>
        <ds_type>1</ds_type>
        <rpt_title>some title rpt_title</rpt_title>
        <rpt_warning>some title rpt_warning</rpt_warning>
    </title>
    <temps>
        <tcode>AAA</tcode>
        <tname>Tripel A</tname>
        <tbbal>9.99</tbbal>
        <tdiff>.24</tdiff>
        <tothd>23</tothd>
        <tbsd>5.00</tbsd>
        <tebal>62</tebal>
    </temps>
    <temps>
        <tcode>AAA</tcode>
        <tname>Tripel A</tname>
        <tbbal>3.99</tbbal>
        <tdiff>1.24</tdiff>
        <tothd>2.03</tothd>
        <tbsd>50.00</tbsd>
        <tebal>63.23</tebal>
    </temps>
    <temps>
        <tcode>AAA</tcode>
        <tname>Tripel A</tname>
        <tbbal>.99</tbbal>
        <tdiff>24</tdiff>
        <tothd>2.3</tothd>
        <tbsd>500</tbsd>
        <tebal>65.23</tebal>
    </temps>
    <temps>
        <tcode>BB</tcode>
        <tname>Double B</tname>
        <tbbal>2</tbbal>
        <tdiff>.24</tdiff>
        <tothd>23</tothd>
        <tbsd>5.00</tbsd>
        <tebal>62</tebal>
    </temps>
    <temps>
        <tcode>BB</tcode>
        <tname>Double B</tname>
        <tbbal>4</tbbal>
        <tdiff>11.24</tdiff>
        <tothd>28.03</tothd>
        <tbsd>5.23</tbsd>
        <tebal>.26</tebal>
    </temps>
    <temps>
        <tcode>BB</tcode>
        <tname>Double A</tname>
        <tbbal>6</tbbal>
        <tdiff>32</tdiff>
        <tothd>223</tothd>
        <tbsd>6.7</tbsd>
        <tebal>12.23</tebal>
    </temps>

</CustomDeferredReport>
```

Comment: Thanks!  The code is simple enough, but the software I'm using is giving me an error when I try to run the report, it says it is unable to load the XML report. I believe it's based on Oracle.  I'm a tax accountant learning to do SQL and XSL for custom reports within our tax provision software.

Comment: Ah, well welcome!  I'm not sure about your environment so can offer no help there.  Let me suggest that you run this in a browser which is easy to do.  I'll provide another solution below with the details to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To run this solution separate of your environment, so to see this run in a browser locally, just add the following deceleration just below the existing xml declaration in your Xml (and to be safe, use my Xml).

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='tcode.xsl'?>
```

Take the XSLT I have written and save it to disk and name it tcode.xsl.  This transformation should work lickity split in IE but if you insist on running it in Chrome, well you have to set a flag that enables local files to run... --allow-file-access-from-files

After adding the xml-stylesheet deceleration to your Xml, drag the Xml into an IE browser and it should transform it.

Comment: kstubs, thanks for your help. I got the grouping to work but another issue popped up.  What is the proper way on this forum to update my question with new XML and XSL code to illustrate this?

Comment: My recommendation is to 1) mark this answered, then 2) ask a new question for the new issue.